# Finding error in JavaCC parser/lexer code

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, javacc

I am writing a JavaCC parser/lexer which is meant to recognise all input strings in the following language *L*:

A string from *L* consists of several blocks separated by space characters.
At least one block must be present (i.e., no input consisting only of some number of white spaces is allowed).

- A block is an odd-length sequence of lowercase letters (a-z).
- No spaces are allowed before the first block or after the last one.
- The number of spaces between blocks must be odd.

The I/O specifications include the following specification:

If the input does represent a string from *L*, then the word `YES` must be printed out to System.out, ending with the EOL character.

If the input is not in *L*, then only a single line with the word NO needs
to be printed out to System.out, also ending with the EOL character.
In addition, a brief error message should be printed out on System.err explaining the reason why the input is not in *L*.

**Issue:**

This is my current code:

```
PARSER_BEGIN(Assignment)

  /** A parser which determines if user's input belongs to the langauge L. */
  public class Assignment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        Assignment parser = new Assignment(System.in);
        parser.Input();
        if(parser.Input()) {
          System.out.println("YES"); // If the user's input belongs to L, print YES.
        } else if(!(parser.Input())) {
          System.out.println("NO");
          System.out.println("Empty input");
        }
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("NO");  // If the user's input does not belong to L, print NO.       
      }
    }
  }

PARSER_END(Assignment)

//** A token which matches any lowercase letter from the English alphabet. */
TOKEN :
{
 < ID: (["a"-"z"]) >
}

//* A token which matches a single white space. */
TOKEN : 
{
  <WHITESPACE: " ">
}

/** This production is the basis for the construction of strings which belong to language L. */
boolean Input() :
{}
{
  <ID>(<ID><ID>)* ((<WHITESPACE>(<WHITESPACE><WHITESPACE>)*)<ID>(<ID><ID>)*)* ("\n"|"\r") <EOF>
  {      
    System.out.println("ABOUT TO RETURN TRUE");
    return true;    
  }

  |

  {    
    System.out.println("ABOUT TO RETURN FALSE");
    return false;
  }
}
```

The issue that I am having is as follows:

I am trying to write code which will ensure that:

- If the user's input is empty, then the text `NO Empty input` will be printed out.
- If there is a parsing error because the input does not follow the description of *L* above, then only the text `NO` will be printed out.

At the moment, when I input the string `"jjj jjj jjj"`, which, by definition, is in *L* (and I follow this with a carriage return and an EOF [CTRL + D]), the text `NO Empty input` is printed out.
I did not expect this to happen.

In an attempt to resolve the issue I wrote the `...TRUE` and `...FALSE` print statements in my production (see code above). 
Interestingly enough, I found that when I inputted the same string of `j`s, the terminal printed out the `...TRUE` statement once, immediately followed by two occurrences of the `...FALSE` statement.
Then the text `NO Empty input` was printed out, as before.

I have also used Google to try to find out if I am incorrectly using the OR symbol `|` in my production `Input()`, or if I am not using the `return` keyword properly, either.  However, this has not helped.

Could I please have **hint(s)** for resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `Input` method three times. The first time it will read from stdin until it reaches the end of the stream. This will successfully parse the input and return true. The other two times, the stream will be empty, so it will fail and return false.

You shouldn't call a rule multiple times unless you actually want it to be applied multiple times (which only makes sense if the rule only consumes part of the input rather than going until the end of the stream). Instead when you need the result in multiple places, just call the method once and store the result in a variable.

Or in your case you could just call it once in the `if` and no variable would even be needed:

```
Assignment parser = new Assignment(System.in);
if(parser.Input()) {
  System.out.println("YES"); // If the user's input belongs to L, print YES.
} else {
  System.out.println("NO");
  System.out.println("Empty input");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the input is `jjj jjj jjj` followed by a newline or carriage return (but not both), your `main` method invokes `Parser.Input` three times.

- The first time, your parser consumes all the input and returns `true`.
- The second and third times, all the input having already been consumed, the parser returns `false`.

Once the input is consumed, the lexer will just keep returning `<EOF>` tokens.